# CCPhysics vehicle on ground?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I am working on a 2d side view driving game in Cocos2d V3.1 using CCPhysics (integrated Chipmunk-Physics).

I have my delegate setup, and the callback is working and I can set a property (like `_onGround`) to true, but I can not figure out how to initially set the parameter to `false`.

My wheels have `collisionType` set to "wheel" and a delegate with a method called

```
-(void)ccPhysicsCollisionPostSolve:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair )pair wheel:(CCNode )nodeA wildcard:(CCNode *)nodeB {
```

The delegate is being called as it is suppose to, but I can not figure out how to reset the value each cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Because a wheel can touch more than one ground object at a time, I would use a counter instead of a flag. Each time you get a collision begin event, increment the value. Each time you get a collision separate event, decrement it. If the count is 0, then you are not on the ground. If it's positive, then you are. No need to handle (multiple) collision events every frame and no need to reset the value between frames.

Comment: ahhh, let me try that and report back.  Thanks.